# Excel - Sumifs with multplie sheets and arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

I am currently using this array formula

```
=SUM((SUMIFS(Actual!$E$1:$E$100000,Actual!$A$1:$A$100000,**E$52**,Actual!$C$1:$C$100000,$A75,Actual!$B$1:$B$100000,E$1:E$44)))
```

This achieves the correct result, however I would like to replace the criteria "E$52" with an array of criteria. eg E48:E60. Similar with what is happening at the end of the formula with E$1:E$44.

When I try to make this change the result is not the expected answer... Thoughts?... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use TRANSPOSE() so in place of E$52 put `TRANSPOSE(E$48:E$60)`

Comment: When doing multiply arrays, the limit is two, one must be horizontal and the other vertical.